# CI with iOS (Objective-C) projects and Hudson

Tags: objective-c, ios, continuous-integration, hudson

At our company we use Hudson for our CI, we use a lot of different languages and they all work well on linux.

We don't do this for our iOS projects. I know we can, using a mac with OSX and build projects using the terminal (command line). But can this be done using for instance Debian? Can one also run the unit tests xCode 4 creates?

The reason I am asking this is because I need to know that ordering a new mac mini (or any other mac) is necessary in order to comply with CI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it sure can be done (i've tried it some time ago) - however, it is questionable whether is it worth the hassle. It is (was) far from straightforward process and from the business point of view the acquisition of a mac mini is way more feasible (i think). However, if you seek challenges you might give it a try, there is a project on [google code called iphone-dev](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-dev/wiki/Building) that should get you started.